# Input_shape with Conv2D error

Tags: keras

I want to use the Keras Conv2D but got errors:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(1, 4, 4, 1)))
```

The Keras doc tells us that input shape is a 4D tensor, but it throws this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5.
```

I did some debugging and found there's a check to parameters in `topology.py`:

```
if spec.ndim is not None:
            if K.ndim(x) != spec.ndim:
                raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) +
                                 ' is incompatible with layer ' +
                                 self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
                                 str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
                                 str(K.ndim(x)))
```

I found that `x = Tensor("conv2d_1_input:0", shape=(?, 1, 4, 4, 1), dtype=float32)` is a tensor with `dim=5` and spec is an instance of InputSpec with `dim=4`, it never is equal. How to solve this problem?

The code :

```
def _build_model(self):
    # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(1, 4, 4, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
    return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(4, 4, 1)))`

The Convolutional2D layer expects #samples * height * width * channels. The number of samples is inferred from your model.fit() function where you feed in you data.

If you look at MNIST as the simplest example, this works:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
...
history = model.fit(X-train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
```